# Connection to server fails after rebooting even though can log into it

Tags: postgresql, freenas

I have been having problem with the electricity going off often for 3 hours and more at a time and the UPS i have is not enough. When the UPS runs out then the servers switch off. When the electricity goes back on things boot up and all servers and VM's go on automatically (running XenServer with a few VM's). The issue I am having is that when the servers switch back on all the VM's go on as normal but there is two webservers that rely on the database and the other 5 don't. The ones that are relying on the database (all the content housed on a FreeNas) both have this error on the live site.

```
**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "192.168.xx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'**
```

The first and second time i saw this error i just restarted the freeNas and then it worked as normal however now this error is back because the server switched off again because of electricity going off (and yes got better UPS so wont go off again unless the electricity is off for 5 hours).

My question is where do i start to try to fix the problem. I restarted everything one by one and then searched the error that comes up and saw a post off someone saying i should try this with no reason at all `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

Comment: This might be a problem with the order in which the computers or processes start, so a client may be starting before the server is accepting connections. Try to postpone the startup of the process that gives that error.

Comment: Log in to 192.168.xx.xx. Find the postgresql logs. Read the last entries to see why the autostart failed to start.